# WIF 1.0 to WIF 4.5 migration

Tags: wif

As far as I can make out, in WIF 1.0, Windows Identity directly derives from IIdentity. In WIF 4.5, Windows Identity derives from ClaimsIdentity which implements IIdentity.

How does this affect migrating my WIF 1.0 applications?

Is everything backward compatible or are there any gotchas?

Can I have both libraries on my development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are breaking changes, see the [Guidelines for Migrating an Application Built Using WIF 3.5 to WIF 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089.aspx) for details.

Comment: Yup - that's the one I used in the end - wasn't available when I asked though - wrote up my experiences here:  http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/07/wif-migrate-from-wif-35-to-wif-45-and.html